# Manipulating screen brightness from within webview on Android

Tags: android, webview, screen, brightness

I'm planning a web-based app for android and I need to know if it's possible to manipulate (gradually fade in and out) brightness on Android devices from within a webview application.
I'm new to Android development so any references would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you want to do? clarify your question.

Comment: That would be a local app composed of webpages. Is it possible to access device screen brightness via Javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes you can**, from java script you can invoke the java function (Android also) (I never try that) and in that function you can access android settings and change the brightness of the screen.